# JSON call with url as parameter

Tags: javascript, json

this does work fine as long the homepage var has no // in it

```
$.getJSON(url + "/addPerson/'" + name + "'/'" + homepage +"'", function(data){console.log(data);} );
```

how would I correctly prepare an url var to pass it as JSON call ?

Comment: what are the possible values for homepage variable??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `homepage` is an URL with `http://` in it you need encode it.

You should write :

```
$.getJSON(url + "/addPerson/" + name + "/" + encodeURIComponent(homepage), function(data){console.log(data);} );
```

If that is the case, you should not pass urls in urls. Use the POST payload or multiform data.

Also, if the aim of the request is to add a record in your database, use POST instead of GET.

```
$.post(url+'/addPerson', {name: name, homepage: homepage}, function(data){console.log(data);});
```

Comment: You need to use `encodeURIComponent`, encodeURI don't encode slashes `encodeURI('http://example.com')` return `http://example.com`

Comment: excellent thanks. that did work. thanks to you all !

Comment: actually only getJSON did work for me

Comment: @user3732793 well you need to make the appropriate changes to your API for the POST request to work properly which I strongly recommend. GET requests are for GETTING data. POST requests are for POSTING data.

Comment: yeah makes sense, I have changed tha api to accept post requests. However your second code example didn't work with it so used the uri compose from the getJSON example...

Answer (score 0):

Use `encodeURI` to encode the uri and get the correct value to the api, when trying to access a api over http

Comment: can you kindly post an example ?

Comment: `$.getJSON(encodeURI(url + "/addPerson/'" + name + "'/'" + homepage +"'"), function(data){console.log(data);} );
`

Comment: @user3732793 Only name and homepage should be encoded use `$.getJSON(url + "/addPerson/" + encodeURIComponent(name) + "/" + encodeURIComponent(homepage)), ...`

Comment: thanks but that does not reach the api  behind Person anymore. Which is currently reduced to "../addPersonen/{param1}/{param2}" as url